# disable html list table and other froala editor

Tags: angularjs, froala

I would like remove html tag like list or table, iframe and script with angular js

I need only

content

do you know how to remove those options?

Comment: Hi & Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular (How do I ask a good question?)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] Do your research,(search)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching] for related topics on SO, & give it a go. If you get stuck & can't get unstuck after doing more research & searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt & say specifically where you're stuck. Peeps will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Do you want to remove the items from the toolbar? it's not clear from your question what you exactly want.